# Precaching online content on Android App for offline usage

Tags: offline

I would like to read the Stack Exchange Android app while offline (no Wi-Fi and mobile data) during my train commute.

Is it possible to preload any pages and read those, like we do with a web browser, visit the pages when you have the Wi-Fi connection, and while offline you can go back to that page and it's loaded?

Is there a workaround like that for the Stack Exchange app?

Comment: I think you should post this as [tag:feature-request] or [tag:support] on [meta.se]. As of current, the app seems to always load the post every time you open a question.

Comment: That is a nice feature which is not supported now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well for offline mode, try using [Pocket - Read It Later](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideashower.readitlater.pro)
For example, when you want to read any article from browser, just click on share and select "Pocket"and then you can read it whenever you want (even in offline mode)